# why is the population standard deviation approximated as the sample standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics

This question addresses calculating a p value from the mean and standard deviation statistics of a sample.  I understand that the -general- philosophy is to divide the sample standard deviation by the root of the population size to get the standard deviation of the sampling distribution, using the assumption that the standard deviation of the sample is roughly equal to the standard deviation of the hypothetical larger population.  Then one calculates a z-score from the number of standard deviations of the sampling distribution to calculate what percent of the time the observed result would have occurred by random chance.  I understand that the particular formula for the sampling distribution standard deviation depends on the particular statistic, say difference of means is a different formula.

The texts and videos that I've looked at use language like "the sample standard deviation is the best number we have available to estimate the population standard deviation."  I just don't find that explanation satisfying.

This approach hinges on the validity of estimating the standard deviation of the entire population as being approximately equal to the standard deviation of the representative sample.  However, we don't make the same assumption that the mean of the population is the approximately equal to the mean of the sample.  At some level, it feels like the final result of significance or non-significance is only self-validating or checking for self-consistency of an assumption that is baked into the methodology.

So to restate, why is the sample standard deviation a good approximation of the populatoin standard deviation, but the sample mean is not a good approximation of the population mean?  I found online an equation for standard deviation of the sampling distribution of standard deviations:

standard error of standard deviation = .71 sample standard deviation / root N.

Does the relative narrowness of the standard error compared to standard deviation play a role in justifying the approximation?

Thank you

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, maybe try https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT

Comment: "So to restate, why is the sample standard deviation a good approximation of the populatoin standard deviation, but the sample mean is not a good approximation of the population mean?"  Why do you think the sample mean is not a good approximation?  It is the best available.  For both the mean and the variance, the means of the sample estimates are equal to the population mean and variance.

Comment: Sample statistics are often used as *estimators* of parameters, and there are ways of comparing estimators to see which are "better." One way is bias, another the variance of the estimator - which you allude to at the end of your question. You want an estimator to have low variance so that you can expect it close to the parameter in practice. Sample mean and (corrected) variance will be the MVUEs of a normal population.Another way of comparing estimators, "maximum likelihood," seeks to construct estimators that maximize the likelihood of the observed statistics.

Comment: In that case, sample mean and (uncorrected) variance will be MLEs of a normal population. Sometimes if the sample size is large enough ($n\ge30$ according to my stats book) by CLT the sample variance is sufficiently close to being normal that we may assume it is. @herbsteinberg An estimator being unbiased doesn't make it the best available. For instance, for a uniform distribution on $[\alpha,\beta]$, the population mean $(\alpha+\beta)/2$ is estimated more efficiently by the mid-range (max-min)/2 than the sample mean.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has followed @GEdgar's recommendation and posted the same question on [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/413214/6633) where it has already received an answer, and the OP has not deleted this one as he should.

Comment: @runway44  Your example is specious.  If you know the distribution (say uniform on $(\alpha,\beta)$) then you can calculate the mean and variance directly.  You don't need to sample.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Estimators are used for populations where the distribution is known or assumed (e.g. uniform, normal, exponential, gamma, geometric, poisson, etc.) except up to certain unknown parameters (which the distribution is defined by), no? I'm not a statistician, but every source I've ever seen on constructing or comparing estimators is in this context, including throughout my statistics class.

Comment: @runway44 Your statement is correct.  But that is exactly the point.  When you know the distribution is uniform, but you don't know the domain, the sample mean IS the best estimate of the population mean.  However in the example you cited previously the domain is known as well, so you don't need to sample at all.

Comment: I never said $\alpha,\beta$ were known in my comment, you just assumed that and I don't know why. The assumption seems bizarrely uncharitable to me, since in the context of estimators people refer to distributions with named but unknown parameters all the time. | You claim the sample mean is the best estimate for the population mean of a continuous uniform distribution on unknown domain $[\alpha,\beta]$, but best in what sense? The mid-range is both the MVUE *and* the MLE in this case. What other sense of "best" are you considering, and can you cite a source?

Comment: You say the mid point is a better estimate, but you also say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unknown.  How you get the mid point?

Comment: @herbsteinberg No, I said the mid-range. That's (max-min)/2 of the sample. Sorry about not @'ing you last comment, I forgot it was necessary for notification.

Comment: @runway44  Do you a derivation which shows that the mid-range of the sample is better than the average?  I'll be surprised, but I am open to such a proof.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I can cite [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Estimation_of_midpoint). I expect the midrange being MLE follows from (max,min) being an MLE for $(\alpha,\beta)$ (which is pretty "obvious" from the definition of MLE). The midrange being MVUE I'm guessing follows from a version of the Cramer-Rao bound.

Comment: IThe Wikipedia article is too terse.  I calculated the variances for a sample of size n using the two methods.  It turns out you are correct.  For a unit interval, the variance for (max+min)/2 is $\frac{n}{2(n+1)^2(n+2)} \approx \frac{1}{2n^2}$, while the variance for the average is $\frac{1}{12n}$

Comment: @runway44: I don't agree that the (min,max) pair $(k,m)$ is "obviously" the MLE for the uniform distribution range parameters $(α,β)$. Actually, I would intuitively guess that the sample range would be $\frac{n-1}{n}$ times the true range, which would imply that the MLE ought to be $[c-d,c+d]$ where $c=\frac{k+m}{2}$ and $d=\frac{m-k}{2}·\frac{n}{n-1}$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @herbsteinberg: Assuming my intuition is not broken, it tells me that using the endpoints of the sample from a uniform distribution is more robust than using the mean of the sample, because we expect one sample point in each $\frac1n$ of the true range, including the leftmost and rightmost part, so we expect the error of the mid-range to be $O(\frac1n)$ with high probability. In contrast, the sample mean has distribution sandwiched between two binomial distributions, and hence has variance $O(\frac1n)$ as you stated. Does this sound right?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I don't agree with closing this question. The 'answer' on Stat SE is so uninformative, and does not address so many points raised in the question.